# Open iterate and show a bmp image in Python

Tags: python, image

I want to open a bmp image and find all black pixels, then change them to white and show the new image. But **I cannot use PIL.** So I need to do it the hard way. This is what I have so far:

```
with open('image.bmp', 'rb') as f:
f.seek(18)
# The width and height are 4 bytes each, so read 8 bytes to get both of them
bytes = f.read(8)

size = struct.unpack('<II', bytes)

# Print the width and height of the image
print('Image width:  ' + str(size[0]))
print('Image height: ' + str(size[1]))
```

Now I want to iterate over the image and find all pixels that is black. But how can I know if a pixel is black?
And also I can save it in the end as new_image.bmp but how can I show it inside a Canvas(I'm using Tkinter)?

Thanks